# SurfaceView exception in Unity 2022

Tags: unity-game-engine, surfaceview

Prior to Unity 2022 I would fetch the SurfaceView by extending the UnityPlayerActivity and then using the following Java code:

```
    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) mUnityPlayer.getView();
    SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) frameLayout.getChildAt(0);
```

After upgrading to Unity 2022, it's throwing an exception:

```
AndroidRuntime java.lang.ClassCastException: com.unity3d.player.J cannot be cast to android.view.SurfaceView
```

How should I get the SurfaceView in Unity 2022?

Answer (score 0):

I exported the Android project and when searching through it I found out that you can get the surfaceView through the following code:

```
SurfaceView surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.unitySurfaceView);
```